# Instagram Graph API get public profile phone number

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Happy coding for everyone!
I need to obtain the email and phone from a friend instagram public profile using the Instagram Graph API.
I am using a long live access token and only let me retrieve a couple of basic information fields but i am stuck on to query another insta public profile and get the user information.

I saw few software that lets you get a bundle of instagram phone numbers, i am trying to make that work ... after days of research still can't achieve this.

{

id: 'xxxx',

username: 'Jhon Doe'

}

This is the example of the response using user_profile scope in the query

https://graph.instagram.com/v15.0/testeridofinstaapp?fields=username&access_token=XXXXXXX

Comment: Are you sure you can request that? and if so Did you request for that permission when creating the OAuth Token?

Comment: A short live token is received after Oauth confirmation (and the permission to access the user profile too), then i exchange the short live for a long live, i am using this, but there is no way, there is few software in the market that achieve this but i am stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The API only allows you to retrieve a user's public profile information, such as their username and profile picture.

Check [Instagram docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/)

Comment: Check this software, it get thousands of phone numbers and emails from instagram as they say but i still cant figure out this with the API, maybe this software is a fake?
https://sistemastecnoinn.com/product/it

Comment: I dont think thats GDPR friendly...

Comment: What about this software? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p38zz64Ygng 
This video show how they easy scrap a user phone from profile.